# outlet collection to detail view controller

Tags: ios, object, uiviewcontroller, iboutletcollection

I have a button outlet collection that gathers the 10 closest store locations and displays them in order. What I am attempting to do is whenever one of the buttons is pressed, it opens a detail view controller and displays the title in the new window. The code I have that declares the query and outlet collection is the following:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        int i = 0;
        for (PFObject *object in objects) {
            if (i >= [self.EventTitles count]) break;
            [(UIButton *)self.EventButtons[i] setTitle:[object objectForKey:@"objectId"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [(UIButton *)self.EventButtons[i] addTarget:self action:@selector(DetailEvent1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            i++;
        }
    }
}];
```

And the DetailEvent1 action code:

```
-(IBAction)DetailEvent1:(id)sender {
    TableDetailViewController *objDetail = [[TableDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    objDetail.??????? = self.????????;
}
```

I need a bit of help writing how to push the selected object forward to the TableDetailViewController. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Please remember to mark the correct answer as the accepted answer to your question, in case any of the answers solved your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To **set the title** of the new view as the one from the button and to **push the new view controller** this code should work (assuming your current view is already inside a `UINavigationController`):

```
-(IBAction)DetailEvent1:(id)sender 
{
    TableDetailViewController *objDetail = [[TableDetailViewController alloc]
                                           initWithNibName: @"TableDetailViewController" 
                                                    bundle: nil];

    // Copy button's title
    objDetail.title = ((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text;

    // Push new view controller
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objDetail animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Do you know why it gives me an error stating "property 'title' not found on object of type 'UIButton'"?

Comment: Yes! My mistake. To get the title of a button, you access it as `button.titleLabel.text`. I have updated the answered already. Let me know if it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the storyboard to create a segue to your new view controller, you can simply call `performSegueWithIdentifier` within `DetailEvent1`. Then set the VC title and pass across whatever data the new VC needs in prepareForSegue.